# footnotebackref does not work with babel or polyglossia for french

Tags: footnotes, babel, polyglossia, back-referencing, french

Whether I use the french language with babel or polyglossia, irrespective of the engine, the back references for the footnotes are missed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf,ifxetex,ifluatex}

\ifluatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmainfont{GentiumPlus}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
%\setmainlanguage{english}
%\setmainlanguage{czech}
%\setmainlanguage{greek}
%\setmainlanguage{russian}
%\setmainlanguage{german}
%\setmainlanguage{hindi}
%\setotherlanguage{english}
\else

\ifxetex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\setmainfont{GentiumPlus}
%\newfontfamily\greekfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\newfontfamily\russianfont{Linux Libertine O}
%\newfontfamily\hindifont{Siddhanta}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage{czech}
%\setotherlanguage{german}
%\setotherlanguage{greek}
%\setotherlanguage{russian}
%\setotherlanguage{hindi}
%\setotherlanguage{english}


%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[babel,french=quotes]{csquotes}
\else

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[french=quotes]{csquotes}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fi\fi

\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\begin{document}
Some text with a footnote\footnote{The first footnote.}\\
Text with the second footnote\footnote[4]{The second footnote.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `babel` and `polyglossia` redefine footnote macros at the beginning of the document, and so undo the changes made by `footnotebackref`. For `babel` this can be turned off, with the command `\StandardFootnotes` but not for `polyglossia`.  Since `babel` works fine with XeTeX and LuaTeX, for most European languages, you should just use `babel` and not `polyglossia`.

However, if you want the footnote formatting that `babel` provides to work with `footnotebackref` much more work will be needed, since that package has not been made `babel` aware.

Your question would have probably received an answer earlier if the example code had not had so much irrelevant stuff in it.  Here's a minimal example that works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\StandardFootnotes


\usepackage{footnotebackref}

\begin{document}
Some text with a footnote\footnote{The first footnote.}

Text with the second footnote\footnote[4]{The second footnote.}
\end{document}
```