# Reference indentation and size in footnotes

Tags: biblatex

The follwing MWE illustrates how I'm making references appear in footnotes as well as in the reference section at the end of my document, with identical numbering. I found this code in a [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/biblatex-which-style-for-a-footnote-once-then-nothing/20741#20741), and all credit goes to [Joseph Wright](http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/) for writing it initially. However, I'd really like to remove the indentation in the footnotes and reduce the font size to `\scriptsize` without redefining `\footnotesize` because I am using it elsewhere. Could somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=165mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=chem-acs,backend=bibtex,sorting=none,maxnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}

@article{ref1,
 author     ={Mulder, J. A. and Kurtz, K. C. M. and Hsung, R. P. and Coverdale, H. and Frederick, M. O. and Shen, L. and Zificsak, C. A.},
 journal    ={Org. Lett.},
 year       ={2003},
 volume     ={5},
 pages      ={1547}
}

@article{ref2,
 author     ={Zhang, L. and Wang, W. and Wang, A. and Cui, Y. and Yang, X. and Huang, Y. and Liu, Y. and Liu, W. and Son, J.-Y. and Oji, H. and Zhang, T.},
 journal    ={Green Chem.},
 year       ={2013},
 volume     ={15},
 pages      ={2680}
}

\end{filecontents}

\makeatletter

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}
        {}
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\begin{document}

First reference. \sfcite{ref1} \\
Second reference. \sfcite{ref2} \\
First reference cited twice. \sfcite{ref1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine `\@makefntext` to do what you want:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{ref1,
 author     ={Mulder, J. A. and Kurtz, K. C. M. and Hsung, R. P. and Coverdale, H. and Frederick, M. O. and Shen, L. and Zificsak, C. A.},
 journal    ={Org. Lett.},
 year       ={2003},
 volume     ={5},
 pages      ={1547}
}

@article{ref2,
 author     ={Zhang, L. and Wang, W. and Wang, A. and Cui, Y. and Yang, X. and Huang, Y. and Liu, Y. and Liu, W. and Son, J.-Y. and Oji, H. and Zhang, T.},
 journal    ={Green Chem.},
 year       ={2013},
 volume     ={15},
 pages      ={2680}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=165mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
  style=chem-acs,
%  backend=bibtex,
  sorting=none,
  maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\makeatletter

\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \scriptsize
  \parindent1em
  \noindent\@makefnmark#1%
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}
        {}
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\begin{document}

First reference. \sfcite{ref1} \\
Second reference. \sfcite{ref2} \\
First reference cited twice. \sfcite{ref1}

\vfill

\noindent{\footnotesize Text in footnote size}\\       
{\scriptsize Text in script size}
\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

For French `babel` you need to redefine a different command, namely `\insertfootnotemarkFB`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{ref1,
 author     ={Mulder, J. A. and Kurtz, K. C. M. and Hsung, R. P. and Coverdale, H. and Frederick, M. O. and Shen, L. and Zificsak, C. A.},
 journal    ={Org. Lett.},
 year       ={2003},
 volume     ={5},
 pages      ={1547}
}

@article{ref2,
 author     ={Zhang, L. and Wang, W. and Wang, A. and Cui, Y. and Yang, X. and Huang, Y. and Liu, Y. and Liu, W. and Son, J.-Y. and Oji, H. and Zhang, T.},
 journal    ={Green Chem.},
 year       ={2013},
 volume     ={15},
 pages      ={2680}
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=165mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[
  style=chem-acs,
%  backend=bibtex,
  sorting=none,
  maxnames=99,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertfootnotemarkFB{%
  \scriptsize
  \parindent=\parindentFFN
  \noindent
  \rule\z@\footnotesep
  \@thefnmark
  \dotFFN\kernFFN
}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
      \iffieldundef{postnote}
        {}
        {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\begin{document}

First reference. \sfcite{ref1} \\
Second reference. \sfcite{ref2} \\
First reference cited twice. \sfcite{ref1}

\vfill

\noindent{\footnotesize Text in footnote size}\\
{\scriptsize Text in script size}
\clearpage

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This example works fine on its own, but once I add your modifications to my document, nothing changes. I first suspected a conflict with `footmisc`, that I am using for its `bottom` feature, but even removing it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Pierre Of course it will conflict with `footmisc`.

Comment: The problem comes from `\usepackage[french]{babel}`, I added my packages one by one to your example and this is the one causing trouble. I already had some trouble with `[french]{babel}` because it modified the bibliography style to small caps automatically, which I solved with `\DefineBibliographyExtras{french}{\restorecommand\mkbibnamefamily}`.

Comment: @Pierre That's very likely as well. I'll see whether there's a workaround.

Comment: Adding `\StandardFootnotes` does the trick apparently. Found it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307791/footnotebackref-does-not-work-with-babel-or-polyglossia-for-french). Thaks again for your help !

Comment: @Pierre I added the trick for French footnote style

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the `memoir` class instead of the `report` class? It makes it possible to change the font of footnotes easily.

Change your class line to:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany]{memoir}
```

And add these lines:

```
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand*{\foottextfont}{\normalfont\scriptsize}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{0in}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0in}
\setlength{\footparindent}{0in}
```

And you should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the `memoir` document class, it screws up my layout and is not compatible with some of the packages I'm using.